# Make a date with just a year and a month in Scala

Tags: scala, date, parsing

This is the problem, I get a date in this format :

1987-12-00 and 1987-00-00
YYYY-MM-DD

I have to parse this String in a Date in scala with just the year and the month. Because sometimes it happens that I do not have the day.

When I'm trying to do that I have exception :

dateHelper.parseDate("1987-00-00")

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Thank you !

Comment: And your problem is? (I.e.: What have you tried so far?)

Comment: What date do you expect from 1987-00-00? This would probably be translated to 1987.01.01 00:00:00.000, because there is no way, that a Date object has no month or day

Comment: When I try to parse it, I got this kind of exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems. Firstly, the examples you gave aren't valid [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, and they are also ambiguous. This puts you outwith standard date types which tend to be quite strict in what dates they accept and model a single point in time. The main problem though is that you don't say what is your desired outcome (hence the -3 vote for your question at the time of writing).

You'll almost certainly first want to write your own parser for this variant date format; use regular expressions if there's some extra variety in the input format, otherwise if it's *always* YYYY-MM-DD, you can wing it with `s.split("-")` as per [Markus's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856572/118875).

That's the simple bit that can be done without really thinking. Now you need to *decide* what a partial date actually *means*, i.e. gather business requirements. For example, if it is sufficient to use the earliest date in the ambiguous period, this sort of thing would suffice:

```
val date = (month, day) match {
  case (0, 0) => new Date(year, 1, 1)       // just a year, assume Jan 1st
  case (_, 0) => new Date(year, month, 1)   // year and month, assume 1st
  case _      => new Date(year, month, day) // full date, excellent!
}
```

Other approaches are to build your own simple date type that has `Option`al values—which suffices if you don't need to do complex date calculations—or take a library such as [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) which has both instant and period types, and combine these into a tuple/object that describes the span of time that the ambiguous date covers.

Answer (score 1):

Not taking error checking into account you can do:

```
def parse(s: String) : (String, String) = {
  s.split("-") match {
    case Array(year, date, _*) => (year, date)
  }
}

val s1 = "1987-12-00"
val (y,d) = parse("1987-12-00")
> y: String = 1987
> d: String = 12
```

With error checking you would need to decide whether you want to wrap it in a Try or Either or some other type.